# Vue / Typescript: Cannot find module 'vue-simplemde'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, import, node-modules

**I can import *most* npm modules with no problem** like axios, firebase, etc.., but for some reason `import MDE from 'vue-simplemde'` throws an error:

```
Cannot find module 'vue-simplemde'.Vetur(2307)
```

The code:

```
<script lang="ts">
   import Vue from 'vue'
   import firebase from 'firebase/app' // Works!
   import MDE from 'vue-simplemde' // Cannot find module 'vue-simplemde'.Vetur(2307)
   import axios from 'axios' // Works!

   export default Vue.extend({
       [...]
   })
</script>
```

package.json:

```
[...]
"dependencies": {
    [...]
    "firebase": "^7.14.4",
    "vue-simplemde": "^1.0.6",
    [...]
  },
[...]
```

The editor does work after compiling the code, but the error remains.
I could ignore the error with `// @ts-ignore`, but this problem produces type checking issues in the whole rest of the Vue component, throwing `Property XX does not exist on type CombinedVueInstance...` errors. Commenting out this import solves those problems.

**Can I make this package compatible with typescript?**
Can I declare a module somehow, somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you can declare a module for this.

I assume you already have a "shims-vue.d.ts"-file in your `src` dir. If not, create one

```js
// shims-vue.d.ts
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue;
}

declare module "vue-simplemde" {
  const mde: any;
  export default mde;
}
```